# Inserting with pyodbc in SQL Server table that has two columns as primary key

Tags: python, sql, primary-key, pyodbc

I am using pyodbc to insert a custom pricelist in SQL Server. My other queries work on the server, but I have difficulty with the following.  When I use SQL Server Management Studio the values are nicely inserted:

```
INSERT INTO abacus_raster.dbo.artikal_cijenovnik_cijena (id_cijenovnik, id_artikal, cijena, order_id, cijena_nab) 
VALUES (13, 46642, 3.30, 1, 2.82)
```

This code does not work in pyodbc:

```
import pyodbc
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=SERVER;'
                      'Database=abacus_raster;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()    
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO abacus_raster.dbo.artikal_cijenovnik_cijena 
        (id_cijenovnik, id_artikal, cijena, order_id, cijena_nab) VALUES(13, 46642, 3.30, 1, 2.82)""")
```

I get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:/dev/cijene/cijene.py", line 109, in 
> (id_cijenovnik, id_artikal, cijena, order_id, cijena_nab) VALUES(13, 46642, 3.30, 1, 2.82)""")
>
> pyodbc.IntegrityError: ('23000', u"[23000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_artikal_cijenovnik_cijena'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.artikal_cijenovnik_cijena'. (2627) (SQLExecDirectW); [23000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]The statement has been terminated. (3621)")

ODBC trace from SSMS:

> cijene          155c-105c ENTER SQLExecDirect
> HSTMT               00D91BA8
> UCHAR *             0x00AEABB4 [     156] "INSERT INTO abacus_raster.dbo.artikal_cijenovnik_cijena \ a        (id_cijenovnik, id_artikal, cijena, order_id, cijena_nab) VALUES(13, 46642, 2.883, 1, 2.62)"
> SDWORD                   156
>
> cijene          155c-105c EXIT  SQLExecDirect  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
> HSTMT               00D91BA8
> UCHAR *             0x00AEABB4 [     156] "INSERT INTO abacus_raster.dbo.artikal_cijenovnik_cijena \ a        (id_cijenovnik, id_artikal, cijena, order_id, cijena_nab) VALUES(13, 46642, 2.883, 1, 2.62)"
> SDWORD                   156

ODBC Trace from python:

> cijene          155c-105c ENTER SQLExecDirect
> HSTMT               00D91BA8
> UCHAR *             0x00AEABB4 [     156] "INSERT INTO abacus_raster.dbo.artikal_cijenovnik_cijena \ a        (id_cijenovnik, id_artikal, cijena, order_id, cijena_nab) VALUES(13, 46642, 2.883, 1, 2.62)"
> SDWORD                   156
>
> cijene          155c-105c EXIT  SQLExecDirect  with return code -1 (SQL_ERROR)
> HSTMT               00D91BA8
> UCHAR *             0x00AEABB4 [     156] "INSERT INTO abacus_raster.dbo.artikal_cijenovnik_cijena \ a        (id_cijenovnik, id_artikal, cijena, order_id, cijena_nab) VALUES(13, 46642, 2.883, 1, 2.62)"
> SDWORD                   156
>
> DIAG [23000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_artikal_cijenovnik_cijena'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.artikal_cijenovnik_cijena'. (2627)
>
> DIAG [01000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]The statement has been terminated. (3621)

This is how the table looks:

[image: Table definition]

Comment: That row already exists in the table and you are trying to insert it again. Maybe you forgot to clear the table before trying again?

Comment: No, I checked twice. I also tried by deleting all rows with id_cjenovnik (pricelist id) that contain value 13.

Comment: I found a temporary solution (not an answer): I wrote the SQL commands in a file.sql and called from python
os.system("sqlcmd -S SERVER-BS -d abacus_raster -i file.sql")

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the effective database permissions for the pyodbc 'user' are sufficient when it hits the database. PYDBC throws cryptic T-SQL errors when the permissions are insufficient. The most aggressive option is to include the sysadmin server role:
[SSMS snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9szkS.png)

Comment: Hi, you should try to describe, what is expected behaviour, what is current behaviour and what you have tried with what result. Only then community will be able to help you.